# fetch 3 rows every day if scheduling for 1 year

Tags: mysql, sql

i have one table bibles that having two columns id, chapter_name and its look like below:-

```
id     chapter_name  
365      chapter_1    
366      chapter_2
367      chapter_3
368      chapter_4
369      chapter_5
370      chapter_6
...       ....
1456    chater_1092
```

Total Records 1092 and id will start form 365 to 1465 fixed. Now user will read 3 chapters every day. Suppose scheduling starts from today i.e is **23rd feb 2020** to **20th feb 2021**. So user requests for 23 feb 2020 it will came 3 chapters and 24th feb 2020 it will came next 3 chapters and so on.

```
id     chapter_name        date
365      chapter_1       2020-02-23    
366      chapter_2       2020-02-23
367      chapter_3       2020-02-23
368      chapter_4       2020-02-24
369      chapter_5       2020-02-24
370      chapter_6       2020-02-24
...       ....
1454    chater_1090      2021-02-20
1455    chater_1091      2021-02-20
1456    chater_1092      2021-02-20
```

So now suppose today is 24th feb 2020 user will see **chapter_4, chapter_5, chapter_6** in the app.
Note:- i dont want to store date column in the table. reason for that i need to update the date columns every year. Can anyone help me how can i fetch 3 records every day. So my expected output for 24th feb 2020

```
id     chapter_name        date
368      chapter_4       2020-02-24
369      chapter_5       2020-02-24
370      chapter_6       2020-02-24
```

Comment: What's the logic for anchoring an id to a date? You need to know that your start point is 23/2 when today is 24/2 to find the relevant 3 chapters..

Comment: @P.Salmon Would appericiate if you can post as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dense_rank()` and arithmetic to put the rows in groups of 3:

```
select b.*,
       ceiling(dense_rank() over (order by id) / 3)
from bibles b
```

The question is then how to get the dates.  Based on your example, this might be:

```
select b.*,
       '2020-02-23' + interval ( ceiling(dense_rank() over (order by id) / 3) - 1) day
from bibles b;
```

However, the `- 1` depends on what the first row is in the the result set.  If you want it to start at 365, then:

```
select b.*,
       '2020-02-23' + interval ( ceiling(dense_rank() over (order by id) / 3) - 1) day
from bibles b
where id >= 365;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')

Comment: select bible_reading_portions.id,bible_reading_portions.portion_name,
       '2020-02-23' + interval ( ceiling(dense_rank() over (order by id) / 3) - 1) day as day
from bible_reading_portions
where id >= 365;  
its giving me all results but i want 3 chapters of date that user requested

Comment: please check my expcetd output