# fetch records based on mysql alias using having clause

Tags: mysql, sql

i am having bibles table where user read 3 bible chapters every day. My query works fine as [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66332123/fetch-3-rows-every-day-if-scheduling-for-1-year) . i have two columns in table id, chapter_name i.e below :-

```
id     chapter_name  
365      chapter_1    
366      chapter_2
367      chapter_3
368      chapter_4
369      chapter_5
370      chapter_6
...       ....
1456    chater_1092
```

and after that i used below query

```
select bibles.portion_name,bibles.id,
   '2020-02-23' + interval (ceiling(dense_rank() over (order by id) / 3) - 1) day as 
  read_date
 from bibles
 where id >= 365;
```

Its giving me blow output :-

```
id     chapter_name       read_date
365      chapter_1       2020-02-23    
366      chapter_2       2020-02-23
367      chapter_3       2020-02-23
368      chapter_4       2020-02-24
369      chapter_5       2020-02-24
370      chapter_6       2020-02-24
...       ....
1454    chater_1090      2021-02-20
1455    chater_1091      2021-02-20
1456    chater_1092      2021-02-20
```

what i want when user requests for date **24 feb 2020** it must come 3 records. currenly its coming all records with actual read date. My expected output is like below:

```
 id     chapter_name        read_date
368      chapter_4       2020-02-24
369      chapter_5       2020-02-24
370      chapter_6       2020-02-24
```

I have tried below query but its giving me error:-

```
select bibles.portion_name,bibles.id,
   '2020-02-23' + interval (ceiling(dense_rank() over (order by id) / 3) - 1) day as 
 read_date
 from bibles
 where id >= 365
 Having read_date ='2020-02-24';
```

ERROR IS

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#4015 - Window function is allowed only in SELECT list and ORDER BY clause
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Move your query without HAVING into CTE then apply WHERE in outer query. The root of the problem is the window function is applied after the output rowset is built (i.e. after HAVING is applied).

Comment: I like Akina's answer.  I think you could also use a sub-query.

Comment: can you post as answer @Akina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub-query as below:

```
select * from 
    (select bibles.portion_name,bibles.id,
       '2020-02-23' + interval (ceiling(dense_rank() over (order by id) / 3) - 1) day as 
     read_date
     from bibles
     where id >= 365) as sub_tab
     where read_date ='2020-02-24';
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where read_date ='2020-02-24' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 7

Comment: read_date column is not there in database ... its created as alias

Comment: I think alias for sub-query was missing in the previous version. Can you please check now?